# NameError Exception: uninitialized constant BCrypt Rails 5, Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt-ruby

I am using `Devise` with `Rails 5` on `Windows`. I know about the problem with `Windows` and `BCrypt` and I am following the instructions from internet to make it work:

1. uninstall all bcrypt gem versions with `gem uninstall bcrypt` and select option 3 (if exist);
2. `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby` and select option 3 (if exist);
3. install bcrypt using `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`;
4. add this line `gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby` to Gemfile.

And I thinks it works, because `Devise` depends on `BCrypt` and `Devise` works fine.

The problem is when I use `Byebug` and use in the console `BCrypt`, I am getting an error:

> NameError Exception: uninitialized constant users::PasswordsController::BCrypt

This is where it is `byebug`:

```
def edit
  byebug
end
```

It is in the controller which inherits from `Devise::PasswordsController` and it just show the view.

For the example, if I type: `BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt`, I am getting that error.

Comment: try `binding.pry`?

Comment: Did you perform the final step: `bundle install`??

Comment: Of course, and `Devise` works fine. It uses `BCrypt`

Comment: I `Ubuntu` I have no problems.